# Android Mobile Frameworks explanation

Tags: android, frameworks

I'm really stuck because I can't find anything that makes clear my questions.

If we use a mobile framework, like KendoUI or jQueryMobile, how does that applications integrate as APK? By PhoneGap? If so, how do we work with the databases of that same frameworks? Don't we need to constantly have internet?

For example, If I work on Java, I work with SQLite. In this Frameworks I could work with PHP..but working with PHP mostly means working with MySQL, and as far as I know I must have internet access to do it (?).

My doubt is how are the data stored in the local database of devices using this frameworks?

**Edit:** I've seen that are people with the same doubts as mine. I did more research and I found a documentation in this case for jQueryMobile framework about handling databases.
http://the-jquerymobile-tutorial.org/jquery-mobile-tutorial-CH22.php

With this, many questions are raised: where is the database stored? In the documentation doesn't tell how is the database created?